# Spring Templates in Docker Container

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, docker

So I've been trying to dockerify my spring-mvc 4 app using the java:8 base image:

I'm having trouble on the following line when running in docker, but outside of docker everything works fine!  It has to do with finding the template files for my project:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/pages/");
}
```

As a note, I've tried running with the template files inside of a jarfile and outside of a jarfile. The url debugging code has shown that it's finding the right files, but when it tries to use them, I get the following exception:

```
engine_1 | jvm 1    |java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pages/saga-index.html] cannot be resolved in the file system for resolving its last-modified timestamp
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.lastModified(AbstractResource.java:155)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.lastModified(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:169)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:229)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
engine_1 | jvm 1    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
```

How can i get through this exception? Why am I not able to get a timestamp?

(More stats)

```
$ docker exec siteconfiguration_engine_1 java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_40-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-internal-b27)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

$ docker exec siteconfiguration_engine_1 df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none             19G  2.5G   15G  15% /
tmpfs          1004M     0 1004M   0% /dev
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1        19G  2.5G   15G  15% /etc/hosts

$ docker exec siteconfiguration_engine_1 ls -l /decision-engine/etc/pages
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 809 Jan  1  1970 saga-index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that, by default, docker drops files as being never modified into an image.  Spring has put in a sanity check on its templates to see if they've ever been updated.  Executing the following commands resolved my problem, and now I'm left thinking that one of these codebases needs a bug report against it.

```
$ docker exec siteconfiguration_engine_1 bash -c 'touch -m /decision-engine/etc/pages/saga-index.html'
$ docker exec siteconfiguration_engine_1 ls -l /decision-engine/etc/pages
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 810 Mar 30 02:39 saga-index.html
```

Here are the bugs that @Rannick created:

- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11916
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12862

Comment: If there's not already an issue for it, I'd file one on Docker. At least other people with similar issues might find it. But the Java exception message isn't great either.

Comment: Opened a ticket against both projects.

Comment: This doesn't happen normally btw; you'll have to add details about your fs and how the filest were added to the report.

Comment: @adrianmouat done (i thought i'd mention id here so it didn't look empty). I'm using boot2docker.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the [Spring Boot with Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) guide, the comment about needing to touch the jar is no longer true if you are using the Spotify docker plugin > v0.2.11. The workaround listed in there and in other answers can be discarded.

Source: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/58

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround that is mentioned in the [spring-boot-docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) documentation (in the 2nd note)

Adding

```
RUN touch my.jar
```

to your `Dockerfile` will solve the problem.